# How solve this? Decompiled .class file bytecode version 51.0 Java 7

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android application, but I'm having problems with the library section I can't read, after I open the library in the Android application. java from the library issued a message with the error "decompiler .class file bytecode version 51.0 with java 7" but after I downloaded the source. android throws this message "could not find E:sources:. required by: project app search in build gradle file" what do I have to do?

what do I have to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.